# How do i create a dropdown menu which puts data from an array in a textfield

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to add this functionality to my form. when a option from a dropdown menu is selected i want it to input the text field above with the corresponding info.

```
objBMW = {
     "Sedan":"5-series",
     "Convertible":"6-series",
     "Truck":"X5",
     "Coupe":"3-series",
     "Hatchback":"5-series GT"
  };

<form name="form1" action="formhandler">

<input type="text" name="typecar">

<select name="BMWCars"> 
<option value="Sedan">Sedan</option> // when this option is chosen put string "5-series" in textfield above
<option value="Convertible">Convertible</option> // when this option is chosen put string "6-series" in textfield above
<option value="Truck">Truck</option> // when this option is chosen put string "X5" in textfield above
<option value="Coupe">Coupe</option> // when this option is chosen put string "3-series" in textfield above
<option value="Hatchback">Hatchback</option> // when this option is chosen put string "5-series GT" in textfield above
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript:

```
document.forms.form1.BMWCars.onchange = function(){
    document.forms.form1.typecar.value = objBMW[this.value];
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xZsc7/

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
<input type="text" name="typecar" id="typecar" />

<?php
$objBMW = array('Sedan' => '5-series', 'Convertible' => '6-series');
?>
<select name="BMWCars" id="BMWCars">
<?php
    foreach($objBMW as $key => $value)
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$key.'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#BMWCars').change(function() {
              $('#typecar').val($("#BMWCars option:selected").val());
            }).trigger('change');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I would do this **only** if I had to deliver the product quickly. Otherwise, I would do my best to avoid mixing Php and HTML code. This is both ugly, and not maintainable in the long run. And I'm sorry but using jquery whereas it's not really needed is like using a sledge-hammer to crack a nut.